# JQuery Append then Remove

Tags: jquery, append, detach

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YbfZG/4/ For some reason the toggleDiv/removeDiv functions aren't working (I haven't used jsfiddle much), but hopefully this will give you a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I've got a page where users can add items (divs) dynamically by making a selection from a dropdown. This is accomplished via .append(). They can also remove an item (.remove()) and potentially re-add it. Each div contains a hide/show area triggered by clicking on a link.

The first time a div is added to the page, the hide/show area works fine. If the same div is removed and then re-added, the hide/show no longer works. I believe this is because the div isn't being completely removed from the DOM, so the hide/show function - which operates based on ids - can't find the correct div to work on.

I've tried modifying my remove function to be $(this).empty().remove(); but that didn't work. I also tried using detach as well, but there was no change in the functionality. I did some reading and I potentially need to be using .on(), but I'm not sure how to structure that.

ETA: Append & toggle code and changed div name to not be solely numeric (typo on my part).

Comment: There is not enough info to help you. You should show us also the code that adds the div. Best thing would be for you to assemble a fiddle, you'd most certainly get an answer that will help you

Comment: Whats the code for your hide/show ?

Comment: Unless you are using html5, numeric `id` values are invalid.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Yep, that was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be easier if you change your markup to:

```
<div id="8" class="wrapper">
    <div>
    <a title="Remove" class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

(basically i added a "wrapper" class to the main div and a "remove" class to the remove link)

So you'll get rid of the `onclick` attribute and use a simple function instead:

```
$('body').on('click','a.remove',function(){
    $(this).closest('div.wrapper').remove();
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/7xuBE/)

---

Given your full code, here's how to make it work (**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/PkEXm/)**) :

```
$(function() {

    $('.elements').on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('div[id^=div]').remove();
    });

    $('.elements').on('click', '.open-close', function() {
        var hideShowN = $(this).closest('div[id^=div]').attr('id').replace(/\D/g,'');
        $('#hide_show_'+hideShowN).toggle();
    });

    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        $('.elements').append('<div id="div_8">Element<a class="open-close" href="#" title="Open/Close">Open/Close</a><div id="hide_show_8" style="display: none;">Stuff</div><a class="remove" href="#" title="Remove">Remove</a></div>');
    });

});​
```

Comment: I think `closest` is a bit cleaner than `parents`.

Comment: This is a valid comment, but it's not an answer to OP's issue

Comment: Right, which is why I said cleaner.  Both will work but there's no need to continue up the DOM looking for additional matches if you only want the one.  In the end a minor difference.

Comment: This won't work for elements that are added dynamically. You need to write it as `$('#container').on('click', 'a.remove', function()...)` to delegate properly.

Comment: @GionaF - I appreciate the cleaner code, and I'll probably use it once this issue is solved, but my hide/show areas still aren't working after making your changes.

Comment: What are your hide/show areas @shimmoril ? can you please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @GionaF - Fiddle added above.

Comment: @GionaF - thanks, that looks like it'll solve the problem. One final snag - when the hide/show link is clicked, I'd actually like to change the image displayed. Previously I was doing that by passing the imageID to the toggleDiv function, but I'm not sure how to integrate that with your changes. The image is inside the Open/Close `a` tag.

Comment: @GionaF - Sorry, I have another question. In my example code, I used _8 for the ids, which is basically a placeholder. Each item will have it's own distinct id number (although removed/re-added items will have the same id). Does your code take that into consideration?

Comment: @shimmoril yes, it's taken into consideration. Not in the `.add` handler, you'll have to work it out. But for the open/close you've this variable: `var hideShowN` which returns the _numeric_ part of your div's id

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use listeners when using jQuery, it's cleaner and often easier.

I've made a jsfiddle with what i think you need. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/YbfZG/2/.

What is important in this example is that the listener that removes the elements is listening on the 'elements' div, not the remove button. When the listener is triggert, THEN it checks if the click was inside ".element .remove", if so, it executes the function.

This is important because if you put the listener directly on the ".element .remove", it would fail for newly added classes through the 'add' button because they were added after jQuery appended the listeners.

Comment: In other words, delegate the click event to an ancestor element and check which descendent it originated from.

Comment: Exactly, it's very important when working with listeners on dynamically created elements.

Comment: I appreciate the fiddle, but since you're adding new elements, it's not quite the same as my problem.

Comment: If you use listeners like this the same way for your hide/show function, I think your problem should be solved

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before. I believe it was caused by the same thing. The issue being that you need to rebind the click handler when you remove/readd the div. What I do is I make a function that binds the handler, and I call it whenever a situation such as this arises, where an element is being added/removed from the DOM.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Use [.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of remove to preserve the event bindings. Quoting from the docs.

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

Comment: Should be noted that this will require that a reference to the element be kept so that the same element is re-added.  This will not work if the elements are re-created.  Unfortunately we can't know since the question does not include this code.

Comment: As previously noted, I tried detach, and it didn't work. Also, given the requirements of this project I don't want to be managing thousands of added & removed divs. Thanks though.